# Simple way to compute the integral $\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{(n + 1)\pi}}\sin(x^2)x \mathrm dx= 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Is there a simple way to show that 
$$\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{(n + 1)\pi}}\sin(x^2)x \mathrm dx= 1$$
if $n$ is *even*. We don't know how to integrate a multiple of functions ($\int{f(x)g(x)}$), but know how integrate $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. Is there some playing with trigonometric identities to show this?

Comment: Substitution? $x^2 = t$.

Comment: something is missing in the integrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments,
$$
x\, dx = \frac{1}{2} d(x^2).
$$
Hence 
$$
\int \sin (x^2) x \, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \sin (x^2) \, d(x^2) = -\frac{1}{2}\cos (x^2) +C.
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_{(\sqrt{n \pi},\sqrt{(n+1)\pi})} \sin (x^2) x \, dx = -\frac{1}{2} \left( \cos ((n+1)\pi) - \cos (n\pi) \right),
$$
and you conclude easily because $n$ is even.

Comment: I thought $\int{sin(x)} = 1 - cos(x)$. No?

Comment: That would be if you had $$\int_0^x \sin (t) \, dt,$$ but the indefinite integral is just $- \cos (x)$.

Comment: Actually the indefinite integral could be $1-\cos(x)$ if you wanted it to be.  Arbitrary constant.  One might write $-\cos(x)+C$ to cover all cases.

Answer (score 0):

As [already commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666102/simple-way-to-show-that-int-sqrtn-pi-sqrtn-1-pisinx2x-1#comment1400456_666102), take $ t = x ^ 2 \implies \frac{1}{2} dt = x dx $. Therefore, the limits change to $ n \pi $ to $ (n + 1) \pi $. And the integral becomes:

$$ \int_{n \pi}^{(n + 1) \pi}{\sin{(t)} \frac{1}{2} dt} = {-\dfrac{1}{2} \left[ \cos{(t)}\right]_{n \pi}^{(n + 1) \pi}} = \dfrac{-1}{2} \left( (-1)^{2k + 1} - (-1)^{2k} \right) \tag{ Take $n = 2k$} $$

From there, you get the integration to be $ 1 $.